# Django form as_table new row

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm creating a table from a form:

```
<form method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_table }}
    <input type="submit" value="register" />
</form>
```

In my `forms.py` I have

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label=u'Username', max_length=30)
    first_name = forms.CharField(label=u'First Name', max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label=u'Last Name', max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField(label=u'Email')
    password1 = forms.CharField(
                                label=u'Password',
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput()
                                )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
                                label=u'Password (Again)',
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput()
                                )
```

The problem is that every field is showing in a single row. how can I have different rows for all fields?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`{{form.as_table}}` returns only `<tr>...</tr>`
You would have to explicitly put the `<table></table>` wrapper around

You can read the [documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#as-table)